# Solar radiation conversion check

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation

I'm analysing some solar radiation data, which is the calculated as the daily sum of PAR in MJ per m$^2$ per day. Assuming that PAR makes 42% from total irradiance, how can I convert this to solar radiation with units of W/m$^2$. I've tried using:

1 MJ m-2 d-1 = 1000000 J m-2 d-1 / 86400 s d-1

i.e. first multiply by 100000, then divide by 86400, and finally divide by 0.42. 
Is this correct? I'm concerned that because the data is provided as the sum of PAR, this would complicate things?

Comment: PAR = photosynthetically active radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate an average power per square metre, but it's going to be a somewhat meaningless figure because the Sun only shines for part of the day and the strength of the sunlight varies continuously throughout the day. But if you want to go ahead this is how to do it.

Suppose the total power (not just the PAR) per square metre is $P$ (in watts per square metre), that means the energy received per square metre per day is $P$ times the number of seconds in a day:

$$ E = P \times 86400 \,J/m^2/day $$

Divide by a million to turn this into megajoules:

$$ E = P \times 0.086400 \,MJ/m^2/day $$

And multiply by 0.42 to get the PAR:

$$ PAR = P \times 0.086400 \times 0.42 \,MJ/m^2/day $$

So to get $P$ just rearrange this to give:

$$ P = \frac{PAR}{0.086400 \times 0.42} \,W/m^2 $$

If you only want the photosynthetically active power just leave out the factor of 0.42.

The total power in sunlight is of the order of a kilowatt per square metre at its peak, so that gives you a target to aim at. Averaged over the whole day I would guess you should get a few hundred watts per square metre.